# How to swap positions of two nodes in a single-linked list, modifying only pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to swap two nodes of a singly-linked list given 0-based indexes into it. In my code, I'm handling many cases but this approach is valid only when `j-i<=2`. If there is a difference of 3 or more between `i` and `j`, I'm not able to handle it.
Please help me to correct my approach.

```
node* swap_nodes(node *head,int i,int j)
{
    if(j<i)
    {
        int temp;
        temp=i;
        i=j;
        j=temp;
    }
    node *prev1,*prev2,*temp1,*temp2;

    if(i==j)
    {
        return head;
    }

    if(i==0  && abs(i-j)!=1)
    {
        int n=0;
        node *temp=head;
        prev1=head;
        temp1=prev1->next;

        while(n<j-1)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
            n++;
        }

        prev2=temp;
        temp2=prev2->next;
        prev2->next=temp1;
        temp1->next=prev1;
        prev1->next=temp2->next;
        temp2->next=prev2;

        return temp2;
    }
    else if(abs(i-j)==1 && i!=0 )
    {
        int n=0;
        node *temp=head;
        while(n<i-1)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
            n++;
        }

        prev1=temp;
        temp1=prev1->next;
        n=0;

        while(n<j-i+1)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
            n++;
        }

        temp2=temp;
        prev1->next=temp2;
        temp1->next=temp2->next;
        temp2->next=temp1;

        return head;
    }
    else if(i==0 && j==1)
    {
        temp1=head;
        temp2=head->next;
        node *temp3=temp2->next;
        temp2->next=temp1;
        temp1->next=temp3;

        return temp2;
    }
    else
    {
        int n=0;
        node *temp=head;

        while(n<i-1)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
            n++;
        }

        prev1=temp;
        temp1=prev1->next;
        n=0;

        while(n<j-i)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
            n++;
        }

        prev2=temp;
        temp2=prev2->next;
        prev1->next=temp2;
        temp1->next=temp2->next;
        temp2->next=prev2;
        prev2->next=temp1;

        return head;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your algorithm seems too complicated. There should not be any abs() needed. Start out by finding the node before `i` and the node before `j` if they exist or if head is `i` or `j`

Comment: i take it you're talking bout a singly linked list and want to swap two nodes based on their index?

Comment: If you swap two nodes the data gets swapped with the node swap, so if you don't want to swap the data, you are just moving pointers around without affecting the data in the list (i.e. there is no net visible effect not counting pointers), so why would you want this?

Comment: @crashmstr Because swapping data in large nodes (ex: a half megabyte of image data) is more expensive than pointer-jockeying. It's much faster to swap a few pointers than to swap a half-megabyte of node data.

Comment: So, to be clear: You want to change the ordering of the link list, by swapping the positions of the two entries, but not physically copy the data into new nodes? One approach would be to add a swap method in the node :-)

Comment: I find that a good way to handle a single-linked list is not to have a pointer to the node, but have a pointer to "an internal pointer to the node" - this internal might be the "root" pointer to the first node, or the "next" pointer from the previous node. Once you get your head round this, it then becomes easy to unstitch a node that you are indirectly pointing to. Having got pointer2s to the two nodes you want to swap out, you also need to consider if they are adjacent, either way round, otherwise it is trivial to swap them. As this looks like homework, and it is the weekend, no more clues!

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, I know. The point of a linked list is moving pointers around to re-order the data without the need to move/copy the data. "Swapping two nodes of linked list without swapping data" leads me to think they want to swap pointers but keep the data in the same order.

Comment: @crashmstr If that were the case, indeed the entire thing would be pointless. Swapping the memory backdrop of two entire nodes, but keeping the content ordering the would be bizarre indeed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basics of pointer-jockeying for swapping nodes in a linked list are simple:

- Find the pointers in the list that point to the nodes you want to swap. One of these pointers can be the `head` pointer, but at least one will be some `next` pointer in the list. Remember these are the pointers that point to the nodes you're swapping.
- Swap those pointers
- Swap the `next` pointers of those nodes to restore the remaining order of the list.
- That's it.

To accomplish this, the simplest approach is to use *pointers to pointers*. This avoids having to tote around `prev` pointers entirely, which makes the algorithm dreadfully more complex than it needs to be.

Your approach is valiant, but overtly complex. Stick with the algorithm above and it becomes much clearer what is needed. Find some pointers pointing to the stuff you want to swap, swap those, then swap back their internal next pointers.

---

Given all of that, the algorithm is implemented as follows (retaining your desire to only scan the list once to find both nodes to swap). Comments on how the algorithm matches with the code are inline:

```
node *swap_nodes(node *head, int i, int j)
{
    if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i == j)
        return head;

    // order i and j
    if (j < i)
        std::swap(i,j);

    // find the pointer pointing to i'th node.
    node **pp1 = &head;
    while (*pp1 && i-- > 0)
    {
        pp1 = &(*pp1)->next;
        --j;
    }

    // finish finding the pointer pointing to the j'th node
    node **pp2 = pp1;
    while (*pp2 && j-- > 0)
        pp2 = &(*pp2)->next;

    // if either index was out of range, at least one of these will
    //  be null, and if that's the case, no swap will happen
    if (*pp1 && *pp2)
    {
        // swap the pointers
        std::swap(*pp1, *pp2);

        // and swap *back* their next members
        std::swap((*pp1)->next, (*pp2)->next);
    }

    return head;
}
```

**Example**

This wouldn't do justice without an in-action example. The following will build an ordered list of ten elements, numbered 1..10. It then uses the zero-index-based swap routine above to swap various elements, notably something that swaps the head node, the tail node, and some internal nodes, then undoes all of that by reversing the swaps to arrive at the list we started with.

```
#include <iostream>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;

    node(int x)
        : data(x)
        , next(nullptr)
    {
    }
};

void ll_print(node const *p)
{
    while (p)
    {
        std::cout << p->data << ' ';
        p = p->next;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

void ll_free(node **head)
{
    while (*head)
    {
        node *tmp = *head;
        *head = tmp->next;
        delete tmp;
    }
}

node *swap_nodes(node *head, int i, int j)
{
    if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i == j)
        return head;

    // order i and j
    if (std::min(i,j) == j)
        std::swap(i,j);

    // find the pointer pointing to i'th node.
    node **pp1 = &head;
    while (*pp1 && i-- > 0)
    {
        pp1 = &(*pp1)->next;
        --j;
    }

    // finish finding the pointer pointing to the j'th node
    node **pp2 = pp1;
    while (*pp2 && j-- > 0)
        pp2 = &(*pp2)->next;

    // if either index was out of range, at least one of these will
    //  be null, and if that's the case, no swap will happen
    if (*pp1 && *pp2)
    {
        // swap the pointers
        std::swap(*pp1, *pp2);

        // and swap *back* their next members
        std::swap((*pp1)->next, (*pp2)->next);
    }

    return head;
}

int main ()
{
    // build a forward-chained linked list of ten items

    node *head = NULL, **pp = &head;
    for (int i=1; i<=10; ++i)
    {
        *pp = new node(i);
        pp = &(*pp)->next;
    }

    // print the list
    ll_print(head);

    // swap the first and second nodes
    printf("Swapping 0,1\n");
    head = swap_nodes(head, 0, 1);
    ll_print(head);

    // swap the first and last nodes
    printf("Swapping 0,9\n");
    head = swap_nodes(head, 0, 9);
    ll_print(head);

    // swap two internal nodes
    printf("Swapping 3,6\n");
    head = swap_nodes(head, 3, 6);
    ll_print(head);
    ////////////////////////////////////////

    // this shoudl swap everything back, so it should give us
    //  what we originally had.

    // swap two internal nodes
    printf("Swapping 3,6\n");
    head = swap_nodes(head, 3, 6);
    ll_print(head);

    // swap the first and last nodes
    printf("Swapping 0,9\n");
    head = swap_nodes(head, 0, 9);
    ll_print(head);

    // swap the first and second nodes
    printf("Swapping 0,1\n");
    head = swap_nodes(head, 0, 1);
    ll_print(head);

    // release the list
    ll_free(&head);
}
```

**Output**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
Swapping 0,1
2 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
Swapping 0,9
10 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 2 
Swapping 3,6
10 1 3 7 5 6 4 8 9 2 
Swapping 3,6
10 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 2 
Swapping 0,9
2 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
Swapping 0,1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

**Summary**

Most of the edge cases you're trying to avoid simply go away if you remember what you're trying to do: swap pointers, not nodes. The trick is finding the pointers (not their values; the actual pointers) that are pointing to the nodes you want to swap, and swap values of those pointers

Comment: Hm, why do you use `std::min()` when a simple comparison is enough? Otherwise, good that someone does it in a sane way.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yeah, that's a good question. it was a replacement for a ternary expression that was originally done in C (indeed, it looks like the actual algorithm was coded in C originally, then retrofitted to C++). I just spaced and dropped in the natural replacement. In a word; *doh* =P. Thanks for catching that; fixed.

Comment: Also, shouldn't the head-pointer be passed by reference, so the node at the start can be swapped if wanted?

Comment: @Deduplicator That's the way I would do it, but the interface provided by the OP returns the (potentially modified) head pointer as the function result (like I said, looks like a C port). I kept that interface for the OP. Personally I would use references, but then personally, I would use a standard container and belay all of this.

Comment: And that standard container would have an iterator- instead of an index-based interface, yeah. I recall there is a [`std::forward_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list).

Comment: @Deduplicator Frankly, I'm amazed some purist hasn't pointed out all those `printf` calls in `main`.

Comment: @Deduplicator This was a far far better approach than what I was doing..Thankyou

Answer (score 3):

You are making your swap logic way more complicated than it needs to be.  Try something like this instead:

```
node* get_node_at(node *head, int index, node **previous = nullptr)
{
    if (previous) *previous = nullptr;

    if ((!head) || (index < 0)) return nullptr;

    node *temp = head;
    while (index > 0)
    {
        if (!temp) return nullptr;
        if (previous) *previous = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
        --index;
    }

    return temp;
}

void swap_nodes(node *&head, int i, int j)
{
    if ((!head) || (i == j)) return;

    node *previous_i, *previous_j;
    node* temp_i = get_node_at(head, i, &previous_i);
    node* temp_j = get_node_at(head, j, &previous_j);

    if (!temp_i || !temp_j)
        return;

    if (previous_i)
        previous_i->next = temp_j;

    if (previous_j)
        previous_j->next = temp_i;

    node *temp = temp_i->next;
    temp_i->next = temp_j->next;
    temp_j->next = temp;

   if (temp_i == head)
       head = temp_j;
   else if (temp_j == head)
       head = temp_i;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/CAxCc7)

Comment: It might work, but it reminds me a bit of *Shlemiel the Painter*.

Comment: It does work (see the link). If you are worried about the 2 calls to `get_node_at()` both starting at `head` and traversing the same nodes 2 times, you could optimize the second call by starting at the node returned by the first call, subtracting the distance between `i` and `j` from the requested index. Then it should take only 1 traversal to find both nodes. Everything else is constant-time after that.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are trying hard to deal with corner cases , but still your code is not able to tackle basic cases and that is because you are making it tough. 
Try to analyse it again - what the task is and what are the requirements for achieving that tasks .

Let me help you : -

- Task 1 - Finding the i'th index node and j'th index node by traversing the linked list .( No need of finding the distance between them )
- Task 2 - Swapping both nodes

Requirements -To swap a node , access to its previous node .(Which seems to be known thing for you , since you've tried it in your code)

Some corner cases -

- If i==j or i>j ( managed by your code )
- If i'th node has no previous node (i.e. it's head of the linked list)

Now try to analyse your code .

For reference , see the code below

```
 node *swap_nodes(node *head,int i,int j)
 {
    if(j<i)
    {
        int temp;
        temp=i;
        i=j;
        j=temp;
    }
    node *prev1=NULL,*prev2=NULL,*temp1,*temp2;
    node *swp;
    int k=0;

    if(i==j)
    {
        return head;
    }
    temp1=head;
    while(k!=i)
    {
        prev1=temp1;
        temp1=temp1->next;
        k++;
    }
    prev2=prev1;
    temp2=temp1;
    while(k!=j)
    {
        prev2=temp2;
        temp2=temp2->next;
        k++;
    }

    // critical part
    prev2->next = temp1;
    swp = temp1->next;
    temp1->next = temp2->next;
    temp2->next = swp;

    // check if prev1 exists 
    if(prev1)
        prev1->next=temp2;
    else
        head=temp2;
    return head;
 }
```

Hope this will help.

Keep asking , keep growing :)

Comment: You are missing semicolon in 2 places `k++`. Also variables `prev` and `c2` don't exist. Please update your code.

Comment: Thanks for the solution..But the thing is that I'm trying tor reverse the entire node..Say you are given with linked list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 and if i=1 and j=5 then the output should be 1 6 5 4 3 2 7..Not just swapping two nodes

Comment: Okay. So for that,1. make a function which takes two node pointers and then reverse the list between those two pointers and return start node of that section ,2. store the node after temp2 in a temporary node pointer , 3.pass temp1 and temp2 in the created function , 4. store returned value in prev1->next  5.traverse the list from that point till node->next exists , 6. make the arrived node->next (which is NULL) to point to node stored in step 2. Then you'll be done with your goal . :)